# PHP Forced download unsuccessful on Android browsers - through Joomla framework

Tags: php, android, joomla, download

I have a download script as follows, run in the Joomla framework:

```
if(headers_sent()) die('Headers Sent');

if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = finfo_file($finfo, $dir.$filename);
    finfo_close($finfo);
} else {
    $type = mime_content_type($dir.$filename);
}
// required for IE
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');  }

jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.file' );
$ext = strtoupper(JFile::getExt($filename));
$no_ext = JFile::stripExt($filename);

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); //need this to recognise in firefox that it is a PDF and not html doc
header('Content-length: '.filesize($dir.$filename));
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); //works on browsers, but still fails on android (rather than unsuccessful) with 'redirect error'
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $no_ext.'.'.$ext.'"'); 
readfile($dir.$filename);
exit; //need to exit otherwise ff thinks this is a html document.
```

This script works fine on all desktop browsers, and Apple products, but fails when attempting on Android almost instantly.  The error given is 'Redirect Error' with a '.bin' file, but using a some slightly different code I get 'Invalid URL'.

However, if I copy this from my asset repository model to a .php page (importing the Joomla framework), and access this via Android, it works perfectly.  The URL when downloading via the model is www.domain.com/resources/download/40-alias-of-file and with the static PHP page: www.domain.com/download.php?id=40

The filename that appears on Android shows up as 40-alias-of-file when downloading via model, but the actual file name given on the PHP page is received by the Android browser. It is exactly the same code, only difference is the URL and routing through controller/model. I've tried appending .pdf to the URL but no luck: www.domain.com/resources/download/40-alias-of-file.pdf - it gives the file a PDF icon but still unsuccessful.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: `Content-Length` should be capitalised as here, but I don't know if that's the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However it doesn't solve the issue in question unfortunately...

Comment: Have you tried toggling the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header? If you run the header/readfile part as a standalone script does that rule out Joomla interfering?

Comment: Commented out Content-Transfer-Encoding, but still no difference.  This exact script works when in a standalone php file (but also importing the Joomla framework), so must be something to do with the fact the code is in a model, or Android gets confused by the URL perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Has this file been previously/recently modified? Have you tried using fpassthru()?

```
if(headers_sent()) die('Headers Sent');

if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = finfo_file($finfo, $dir.$filename);
    finfo_close($finfo);
} else {
    $type = mime_content_type($dir.$filename);
}
// required for IE
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');  }

jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.file' );
$ext = strtoupper(JFile::getExt($filename));
$no_ext = JFile::stripExt($filename);
$fd = fopen($dir.$filename, "rb");

header('Pragma:  '); //I am surprised it worked with IE without this
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary'); //Try also without this header
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($dir.$filename));
header('Content-Type: '.$type); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $no_ext.'.'.$ext.'"'); 

if ($fd) {     
   fpassthru($fd);         
   fclose($fd);              
   exit();         
}
```